Can you help me to identify the aircraft in a 1920s photograph?
Can anyone identify the aircraft in this photograph? The photograph was taken in Belgium in the summer of 1926. Does that say ‘Imperial Airways’? Thank you!


Somewhat out of focus but another image of the same aircraft.
https://digital.lib.buffalo.edu/items/show/9240

I believe this is a Armstrong Whitworth AW154 Argosy.

(photo source, CC-BY-SA 3.0)
The taper on the engine pod looks correct, it appears to be similar dimensions to the photo in the question.
Per BAE they were used for passenger service UK-Paris beginning in 1926, and Brussels is mentioned:

The AW154 Argosy was used on routes to Paris, Basle, Brussels and Cologne

I thought it might've been a DH.66, but its engines are mounted to the lower wing.

I believe it is an Armstrong Whitworth Argosy, specifically the MK.I as that was in service with Imperial Airways in 1926:

This is based on the shape of the rear door, the two large main wheels, the position of the registration relative to the door, the styling of the windows, the uncowled wing-mounted engines, and the straight lower fuselage.
